# Mocking Java 11 HttpClient?

Tags: mocking, mockito, httpclient

I've been trying to mock Java 11's HttpClient but I've been having trouble. This is what I have so far:

```
public class ApiPokerTest {
HttpClient client = mock(HttpClient.class);

@Test
public void poking_api_returns_list_of_modules() throws Exception {
    HttpResponse<String> resp = mock(HttpResponse.class);
    when(resp.body()).thenReturn("Hello world");
    when(client.send(any(), any())).thenReturn(resp);
}
```

}

This doesn't work because any() doesn't match HttpResponse type. All I want is when the client calls send() it returns a mocked response with given JSON. How can I do this?

Comment: Really depressing to see this without an answer. Having the same problem.

Comment: 1. this code fails due to generics use the following to indicate type `HttpResponse<String>`
`when(httpClient.send(any(), any(HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString().getClass()))).thenReturn(resp);`
2.`HttpClient` is abstract (and `HttpClientImpl` is final ..) you should `@Spy HttpClient client`

Answer (score 1):

use mockito `@Spy`

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) // using junit5


@Mock 
HttpResponse<InputStream> mockResponse;

@Spy 
HttpClient httpClient;

void test() throws Exception {
  when(httpClient.send(any(), any(HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream().getClass())))
    .thenReturn(mockResponse);
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason this took me over an hour to figure out, trying all sorts of solutions on Stack Overflow. In the end @ezer's answer helped me, and I didn't even have to use @Spy.

I simply mocked these 2 things:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyTest {

  @Mock HttpResponse<String> response;
  @Mock HttpClient httpClient;

  ...
```

And I made sure `sendAsync` returns the mocked response:

```
when(httpClient.sendAsync(any(), any(HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString().getClass())))
    .thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response));
```

And finally made the mocked response return what I wanted. I only cared about the body:

```
when(response.body()).thenReturn("A mocked response!");
```

I think the key I was missing was the `HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString().getClass()`. Before, I kept getting errors because the second parameter of `sendAsync` is a generic, T. I think specifying the class that way resolved the generic parameter issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Mockito` can't mock `final` classes (HttpClientImpl is such class) out of the box. Use `Spock` and its `MockingApi`. With this testing framework you can write test case like this:

```
given:
def client = Mock(HttpClient)

when:
def response = Mock(HttpResponse)
def responseBody = { 'Hello world' } as Supplier<String>
1 * response.body() >> responseBody
1 * client.send(_ as HttpRequest, _ as HttpResponse.BodyHandler) >> response
def mockedResponseBody = client.send(HttpRequest.newBuilder()
    .uri(new URI('http://localhost:8080'))
    .build(), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding()).body()

then:
mockedResponseBody.get() == responseBody.get()
```

If you insist using Mockito you have to add `mocito-extensions` directory in `test\resources` with `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` file with line `mock-maker-inline` inside.